# check text is right align or not in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, right-align

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  |number  |
1 |122     |
2 |345     | 
3 |     456|
4 |     789|
```

I want to change it into:

```
  |number|
1 |nan|
2 |nan| 
3 |456|
4 |789|
```

i want only right align value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need test [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) if space, then replace to `NaN` by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), remove possible traling spaces by [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and convert to floats:

```
df['number'] = df['number'].mask(df['number'].str.endswith(' ')).str.strip().astype(float)
```

Or:

```
df['number'] = df['number'].mask(df['number'].str[-1] == ' ').str.strip().astype(float)

print (df)
   number
1     NaN
2     NaN
3   456.0
4   789.0
```

If want integers it is possible by [integer na](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) working in pandas 0.24+:

```
m = df['number'].str.endswith(' ')
df['number'] = df['number'].mask(m).str.strip().astype(float).astype('Int64')

print (df)
   number
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     456
4     789
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the strings and grab the end element from the split and convert to numeric using [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['number']=pd.to_numeric(df['number'].str.split(' ').str[-1],errors='coerce')
```

Tested on:

```
s=pd.Series(['122 ','345 ',' 456',' 789'])
pd.to_numeric(s.str.split(' ').str[-1],errors='coerce')
```

---

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    456.0
3    789.0
dtype: float64
```